# How does one understand the [verb] + 在了 grammar structure?

Tags: grammar

From random Internet sites, we can see many examples of the grammar structures:

> [verb] + 在了

> 手机**忘在了**出租车上。
> 我**站在了**舞台上。
> 因为人不在，快递员就**放在了**门口。
> 小男孩被父亲故意**丢在了**超市。
> 闺蜜和男友**睡在了**一起。
> <sub>(Google the quotes surrounded by quotation marks to see the source(s).)</sub>

I think I get the gist from these examples.  It looks like adding 在 modifies a verb, e.g., 忘 = "to forget" turns into 忘在 = "to forget at".  The 了 is the [completion 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_completion_with_%22le%22), added after the modified verb 忘在了 (so we don't write 忘了在 [or do we?]).  在了 doesn't seem to be used in the same way without a preceding verb (but we can say 不在了 or 没在了 to mean "not here", sometimes as a euphemism for being dead).

However, there may be a better way to understand this.  I'm wondering if there is a more rigorous treatment available.  I didn't find a reference from Google, not at the Chinese Grammar Wiki.

**Question**: How does one understand the [verb] + 在了 grammar structure?

Comment: 1.手机忘在了出租车上  2.手机忘了在出租车上  3. 手机忘在出租车上了 -- (2) and (3) seem more common than (1) which I rarely hear people say

Comment: I remember being thrown off by this one when I encountered it the first time(s) too. It is quite common, though, so let's hope someone writes a good answer, because I want to know as well (I just accepted that it's sometimes written like that (rarely spoken, I think) and moved on).

Answer (score 1):

在了 is very common, even colloquially, but it'd be better to see it as separate 在 and 了.

The usage of 了 and its position in a sentence is complex. In the example sentence

> 手机忘在了出租车上,

1. 忘 here can be understood as a [labile verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labile_verb) (perhaps?), meaning "be forgotten".
2. 在 is a **结果补语 (complement of result)**.  Accroding to 刘月华(Liu Yuehua) et al.'s 《实用现代汉语语法》(*Practical Modern Chinese Grammar*, I'll refer to it as Gr from now on), the function of 在 is to "表示通过动作使人或事物处于某个处所，后边一定要有处所宾语" (convey the idea that something or someone is placed in some position via an action, and must be followed by an object of location).
3. 出租车上 is the **处所宾语 (object of location)** of 在. The object 出租车, or taxi, usually can't convey the idea of location on its own, but can do so when compounded with the adverb of position 上.
4. 了 is a **动态助词 (aspect particle)**.  According to Gr, it's a bit complex; for a verb like 忘 in the sense of "to leave something at some place", 了 means the action has happened and has ended.

I think your problem here can boil down to *where should the article 了 be in this sentence?*

According to Gr, "如果谓语动词后有结果补语，“了”位于结果补语后：动词＋结果补语＋“了”＋宾语" (**if there is a complement of result after the verb, then 了 is placed after the complement of result: verb + complement of result + 了 particle + object**). So,

手机(Subject)忘(Verb)在(Complement)了(Particle)出租车上(Object)。

This rule can explain the first four sentences you provided. I think the fifth one is the same, but I'm unsure for now.

Also, please note that in every sentence you provided, 了 can be placed at the very end. This kind of 了 is called a 语气助词 (Modal particle), and the meanings of some sentences will change when you move 了 to the end, and some will not change very much. However, this is a much more complex grammar mischief of Chinese and I don't consider myself capable of talking about it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

在... is prep phrase working as a compliment. E.g. 放[在门口]了.  了 is for completion.  放在了门口 is a variant of 放在门口了.  I think it might be because we say 放在 so often that we take it as a verb as a whole.  So both 放在哪里了 and 放在了哪里 are correct.

So, 手机忘在了出租车上 = 手机忘在出租车上了. 小男孩被父亲故意丢在了超市 =小男孩被父亲故意丢在超市了. etc.